# Blazor Server EF Core: Related data (one-to-many relationship) does not save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

***`SalesItemNecessities` are created when adding an new `Activity`. However, the `SalesItemNecessities` do not get updated when updating the parent `Activity`. Anyone any tips?***

I have two models:

```
public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SalesItemNecessity>? SalesItemNecessities { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class SalesItemNecessity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SalesItem SalesItem { get; set; }
    public int SalesItemId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

When I am changing the data of an `activity`, I can also add, change or remove `SalesItemNEcessities`. When I hit 'save' I want my `activity` to update, but ***also*** my `SalesItemNecessities`. However, the latter does not happen.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Activity objActivity)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            _db.Entry(objActivity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.Set<Activity>().Update(objActivity);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I hit save, the data of my `Activity` is updated in the database (the name e.g.), but my `SalesItemsNecessity` is not updated. Added items are not created, changed items are not updated, removed items are not deleted.

I find this behavior strange since I am able to add a new `activity` with `SalesItemNecessity` with the code below. Any `SalesItemNecessity` is added to the database with the `ActivityId` of the activity EF Core just created.

```
public async Task<bool> AddAsync(Activity objActivity)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            _db.Activities.Add(objActivity);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Anyone any idea why I can not update/remove my `SalesItemNecessities` this way, but I can add them while creating an new `Activity`. Thanks in advance!***

Comment: It is by. design. EF do not update attached related entities. If you want to update related entity via `Update` - do it explicitly.

Comment: Read [DbSet<TEntity>.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-7.0) and [EntityEntry.State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.state?view=efcore-7.0). Remove `_db.Entry(objActivity).State = EntityState.Modified;` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If You create a DbContext, set the objActivity Entity State like **Modified**, then Update objActivity, only it will be updated, because the SalesItemNecessities collection still remain in the **Unchanged** State.

The correct way is:

1. create  **_db** DbContext;
2. load objActivity;
3. load objActivity collections:  **_db.Entry(objActivity).Collection(c => c.SalesItemNecessities).Load();**
4. modify objActivity, changing some elements of its collection also;
5. **_db.Update(objActivity);**
6. **_db.SaveChanges();**

...so You won't need to change any **state**, because EF will do for You. Ef will change to modified, the state of updated elements only, and these only will be sent to the database.

Comment: can you post an example code?

Comment: I'm trying to create a service/repository standard which I can use to CRUD all my entities

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be like that:

```
Activity firstActivity = new Activity()
{
    Name = "My First Activity",
    SalesItemNecessities = new List<SalesItemNecessity>
    {
        new SalesItemNecessity() { SalesItem = "Bike", Amount = 10 },
        new SalesItemNecessity() { SalesItem = "Car", Amount = 100 },
        new SalesItemNecessity() { SalesItem = "Truck", Amount = 300 }
    }
};

CRUD operation = new CRUD();
operation.AddAsync(firstActivity);

int idToUpdate = 1;  //we suppose to update the first ID

Activity updActivity = new Activity()
{
    Id = idToUpdate,
    Name = "Update Activity",
    SalesItemNecessities = new List<SalesItemNecessity>()
    {
        //we want to add this item to the collection
        new SalesItemNecessity() { SalesItem = "Boat", Amount = 900 }
    }
};

operation.UpdateAsync(updActivity);
```

and, supposing We want to add the elements to the collection (but You can easily change the code, if You want to replace some elements), the class CRUD could be:

```
public class CRUD
{
    public async Task<bool> AddAsync(Activity objActivity)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _db = new MyContext())
            {        
                _db.Activities.Add(objActivity);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Activity objActivity)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _db = new MyContext())
            {
                Activity dbActivity = _db.Activities.Find(objActivity.Id);
                _db.Entry(dbActivity).CurrentValues.SetValues(objActivity);                                                                        
                _db.Entry(dbActivity).Collection(c => c.SalesItemNecessities).Load();
                foreach (SalesItemNecessity sal in objActivity.SalesItemNecessities)
                    dbActivity.SalesItemNecessities.Add(sal);                          
                                
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```